# Printing values from list within an input range

Tags: python

I have an unordered list, let's say:

```
lst = [12,23,35,54,43,29,65]
```

and the program will prompt the user to input two numbers, where these two numbers will represent the range.

```
 input1 = 22
 input2 = 55
```

therefore, 22 will be the lowest range and 55 will be the largest range. then with these two range, i want to print the values in the list within these range which are:

```
23
29
35
43
54
```

Here's my code:

```
def valRange(input1,input2,l):
n = len(l)
i = 0
upper = input2
lower = input1
while i<n:
    if (lower<=l[i]<=upper):
        l = l[i]
    i+=1
return l

print(valRange(input1,input2,lst))
```

I'm getting an error saying int object is not subscriptable. Am I comparing it right?

Comment: What is `l = l[i]` supposed to do? You've assigned `l` to an integer and you're later trying to do `l[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning an integer to variable l (previously it was a list) at line 8.

Then, in next iteration it tries to get i'th element of an integer. Which results in error of course.

Try this;

```
def valRange(input1,input2,l):
    result = []

    n = len(l)
    i = 0
    upper = input2
    lower = input1
    while i<n:
        if (lower<=l[i]<=upper):
            result.append(l[i])
        i+=1
    return result

print(valRange(input1,input2,lst))
```

Comment: List comprehension is more pythonic.

Comment: Definitely. I did not want to change the original function as much as possible though.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with a easier solution, using a `generator`:

```
lst = [12,23,35,54,43,29,65]
lowest = int(input())
highest = int(input())
[print(element) for element in lst if lowest <= element <= highest]
```

You will get:

```
23
35
54
43
29
```

If you need to get another list instead of printing the elements you can go with:

```
new_list = [element for element in lst if lowest <= element <= highest]
```

Comment: The purpose of list comprehension is just for generate list.

Answer (score 0):

much easier:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
def valRange(input1,input2,l):
    return sorted([x for x in l if input1 < x < input2])

lst = [12,23,35,54,43,29,65]
input1 = 22
input2 = 55

print(valRange(input1,input2,lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

This should meet all criteria:

```
lst = [12,23,35,54,43,29,65]
lst.sort()
l = int(input("Enter min: "))
h = int(input("Enter max: "))
i = 0
while i < len(lst):
  if l < lst[i] < h:
    print(lst[i])
  i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have wrong tried this line `l = l[i]`. You have a list name as `l`. Then you declare a variable `l` thats same name with list `l`. So, you are getting error : `int object is not subscriptable`.

So, You have to declare a `new list` where you want to store the valid value.

So, you can follow this preocess  :

```
lst = [12,23,35,54,43,29,65]

def valRange(input1,input2,l):
    n = len(l)
    new_lst = [] # new list for storing valid value bewtween two range.
    i = 0
    upper = input2
    lower = input1
    while i<n:
        if (lower<=l[i]<=upper): # if any value of l in this range .
            new_lst.append(l[i]) # append to the new_lst this value.
        i+=1
    return sorted(new_lst) # return all value as sort.


input1 = 22
input2 = 55
print(valRange(input1,input2,lst))
```

Output :

```
[23, 29, 35, 43, 54]
```

**You can also try to solve this problem `pythonic` way.** Like this :

```
>>> lst = [12,23,35,54,43,29,65]
>>> input1 = 22
>>> input2 = 55
>>> new_list = sorted([val for val in lst if input1 <= val <= input2])
>>> new_list
[23, 29, 35, 43, 54]
```

Comment: List comprehension is more pythonic.