# Using an array and storing values in it

Tags: python, arrays

I know this may be a very basic question but let's say, I have an array:

```
array = [23,43,54,12,29,65]
```

and then I prompt the user to key in two integers which would be the range:

```
u1 = 12
u2 = 55
```

so now, what i want to do is to print out the values from the array that is within the boundary of `u1` and `u2`. this case it would be:

```
[23,43,54,12,29]
```

the problem I'm facing now however is I'm not able to use append when it comes to printing out the output. The code:

```
lst = [23,43,54,12,29,65]
u1 = 12
u2 = 55

def valRange(input1,input2,l):
    result = []

    n = len(l)
    i = 0
    upper = input2
    lower = input1
    while i<n:
        if (lower<=l[i]<=upper):
            result.append(l[i])
        i+=1
    return result

print(valRange(u1,u2,lst))
```

The code works and prints out perfectly. the problem is I'm not supposed to use `result = []` and `append()` because I will be translating into assembly code. Are there any alternatives to print an array containing `l[i]` in the function without the use of `append`?

Comment: You can use a list comprehension `[x for x in lst if lower_bound <= x <= upper_bound]`

Comment: @Pythonista That's a list comprehension, not a Monad (?)

Comment: Python's lists are not exactly the same as arrays in assembly code, and it's not obvious how you're expected to use them if you can't use the standard list operations (like `append`). Does your homework assignment tell you what operations you *are* allowed to use?

Comment: @Blckknght because the assembly language I'm using does not have list but arrays instead. Hence, append is not possible.

Comment: Sure, but *what does your assembly language have*? We can't tell you how to emulate some unknown type of array if we don't know anything about it. How do you allocate memory in your assembly language? Are you calling `malloc` in the C library? Or is all memory statically allocated ahead of time?

Comment: Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45648067/printing-values-from-list-within-an-input-range/45648171#45648171).

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe sort your array then find the lower index and the upper index.

your lower index is the first value which is > to your lower bound same for the upper index except it's < to your upper bound.

Finally slice your array between those 2 index.

```
slice = lst[lower:upper]
print(slice)
```